# Is it possible to use an html page as a view in play framework 2?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am fairly new to Play 2.0 - I try searching for samples but always keep on getting Scala templates as the view for directing the content to, is it possible to just use a non Scala based, pure html file as a view? How do you ask the Controller's action method to direct it to that html file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, put your HTML files in the `public` folder, for example:

```
public
  |
  ├── html
      |
      └── hello.html
```

And then you can serve static HTML files using several ways with the [Assets controller](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.x/scala/index.html#controllers.Assets%24):

Either by refering to the file directly in the Url: `http://localhost:9000/assets/html/hello.html`

Either by using the `routes` file to map an Url to your file. In the `routes` file, add:

```
GET /hello  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="html/hello.html")
```

Then access the Html using `http://localhost:9000/hello`